# Npgsql 5.0.0.0 transaction completed and it is no longer available

Tags: npgsql

After upgrading nuget package for Npgsql to version 5.0.0.0 I have started to receive the following exception in my web API 2 project:

**Transaction completed and it is no longer available**
when calling dbContext.SaveChanges()
it works perfectly with NpgSQL 4.15 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql :
the sample code is the following :

```
using (MyDBContext dbContext = new MyDBContext())
            {
                using (DbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                      dbCntext.Jobs.Add(new Job());
                      dbContext.SaveChanges();
                      dbCntext.Subset.Add(new Subset());
                      dbContext.SaveChanges();
                      dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
            }

[![Stack trace][1]][1]
**System.InvalidOperationException: This NpgsqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.**

   à Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.CheckReady()
   à Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.get_DbConnection()
   à System.Data.Common.DbTransaction.get_Connection()
   à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.<>c.<GetConnection>b__4_0(DbTransaction t, DbTransactionInterceptionContext`1 c)
   à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.GetConnection(DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.get_CurrentTransaction()
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.ClearCurrentTransaction()
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
   à System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction.Commit()
```

Is there any changes in version 5.0.0.0 of NpgSQL that brakes the EntityFramework6.Npgsql usage ?

the project is a .Net 4.8 Framework project using code first with EntityFramework6

Thanks for help.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1593, will follow up there.

Comment: ok thanks I will the github issue